# Is there a retry count setting for svscan?

Tags: services, daemon, daemontools

I'm supervising a script with svscan which may run into errors and stuck there. When the script dies svscan restarts it right away but dies immediately. So it keeps restarting it.
I don't seem to find any setting or configuration for svscan such as a retry count or something. 
Are you aware of anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

The original Bernstein daemontools has no mechanism for this.  There is only a `run` program in the service directory and a fixed auto-restart policy.  However, several members of the daemontools family have improved upon this, and have flexible general-purpose mechanisms that can be employed to address such situations.

- [Gerrit Pape's runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) and [Laurent Bercot's s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/) both provide the mechanism of a `finish` program.
- [Bruce Guenter's daemontools-encore](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/) provides the mechanism of a `notify` program.
- [Wayne Marshall's perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/) has the mechanism of invoking the `rc.main` program with the `reset` subcommand.
- [My nosh toolset](https://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/) provides the mechanism of a `restart` program.

These are all general-purpose mechanisms that can be used in your situation.  I'm just going to discuss nosh service management in further detail here.  It should be fairly obvious how to apply this to the others.

### auto-restart control in nosh

In nosh service management, the same extended (relative to the Bernstein original) service states are employed as by daemontools-encore: *stopped*, *starting*, *started*, *running*, *failed*, and *stopping*.

Before a service is started, when it is in the *starting* state, the nosh service manager runs the `start` program.

When a service terminates, and it is still "up", the nosh service manager runs the `restart` program, in the *failed* state, to determine whether to transition back to the *running* state or to the *stopping* (and thence to the *stopped*) state.  The `restart` program makes this determination for it, in a service-specific way, and it is explicitly the place to put decisions about whether a service has restarted "too many times" or has become unrestartable in some other way.

`restart` is passed, as command-line arguments, information about how the main service process terminated (whether it was a normal exit or in response to a signal, and the exit code or specific signal).  The service manager chooses to transition back to the *running* state if the `restart` program can be run and terminates with a success status, and transitions to the *stopping* (and thence *stopped*) state otherwise.

`restart` and `start` can be anything that you like: Perl programs, shell scripts, execline programs, compiled binaries, and so forth.  They are fairly trivial exercises in shell scripting, with `case`…`esac` and `if`…`fi`.  There are some examples of `restart` programs written in shell script supplied in the nosh-bundles package, which is available [for Debian/Ubuntu](https://jdebp.eu./nosh/debian-binary-packages.html#Bundles) and [for FreeBSD/PC-BSD/DragonFlyBSD/&c.](https://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/freebsd-binary-packages.html#Bundles).

So to make a decision about whether a service has been restarted "too many times" you have your `start` program zero-initialize a counter (in a file in the service directory) and your `restart` program increment that counter and only return a success status if the counter is less than a certain value.  Of course, you can make the decision include more and other factors.

- You might, say, also want to stop auto-restarting if the service crashes or aborts with a signal and only auto-restart if it exits cleanly or is cleanly terminated by a "clean termination" signal such as `SIGTERM`.
- You might, say, want to stop auto-restarting if you detect that the service has become corrupt (in some service-specific way) to the extent that it cannot ever again start properly without administrator intervention.
- You might, say, want to introduce some sort of rate throttling mechanism, involving a calculated `sleep` period.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*The daemontools family*](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/daemontools-family.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard. [`service-manager`](https://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/service-manager.html).  *nosh Guide*.

  The *nosh Guide* is available as [a Debian/Ubuntu package](https://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/debian-binary-packages.html#Doco) and [a FreeBSD/PC-BSD/DragonFlyBSD/&c. package](https://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/freebsd-binary-packages.html#Doco), and the `service-manager` manual is accessible on your machine without any Internet connection required via:

  - `man service-manager`
  - `xdg-open /usr/local/share/doc/nosh/service-manager.html`
- Bruce Guenter.  [`supervise`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/supervise.8.html).  daemontools-encore manual.  §8.
- Gerrit Pape.  [`runsv`](http://smarden.org/runit/runsv.8.html).  runit manual.  §8.
- Wayne Marshall (2013). [`perpetrate`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=perpetrate.5).  perp manual.  §5.
- Laurent Bercot.  [`s6-supervise`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-supervise.html).  s6 manual.  Skarnet software.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing that [`svscan`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/svscan.8.html) has no flexibility, you might consider [`monit`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/monit), which is scriptable.